# Interesting Observation About Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, segmentation-fault

So, my code is below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
bool comp (pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b) {
    if (a.second==b.second) return a.first<b.first;
    return a.second<b.second;
}
int main () {
    int n, m;
    bool visited[n+1];
    cin>>n>>m;
    int mat[n+1][n+1];
    vector<pair<int, int> > v;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            cin>>mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    queue<pair<int, int> > q;
    q.push(make_pair(m, 0));
    visited[m]=1;
    //for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) { for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) { if (mat[i][j]!=0&&mat[i][j]!=1 )cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";} cout<<endl;}
    while (!q.empty()) {
        pair <int, int> curr=q.front();
        v.push_back(curr);
        q.pop();
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            if (mat[curr.first][i]&&!visited[i]&&curr.first!=i) {
                q.push(make_pair(i, curr.second+1));
                visited[i]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
    int cdist=0;
    for (pair<int, int> i: v) {
        if (cdist!=i.second) cout<<endl;
        cdist=i.second;
        cout<<i.first<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know where the issue is, don't have to grill me on this, that I declared a visited array of length [n+1] before n was declared. This was an experiment. What I found was interesting is that if I included the commented out line in the code, the last loop in the code would print exactly what I wanted, and if I excluded it, the code wouldn't print anything. Why is this phenomenon occurring?

Comment: the lovely _undefined behavior_ (since you never initialize `n`)... on my pc both the versions generate a segfault

Comment: **undefined behavior**, so literally *anything* can happen, including *seemingly correct* behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior can be a segment fault, it could work correctly, or cause Nasal Demons.

Comment: This isn't that uncommon. It is one of the more difficult aspects of Undefined Behavior. A lot of the time it behaves as you expected, hiding the error until much later when a seemingly unrelated change causes it no longer work. It can be incredibly difficult to track down, because the problem doesn't usually occur near the cause of the problem. By that time, you wouldn't suspect old code that has been working without problem for a long time.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow you to declare variable-length arrays, so you're also depending on a GCC extension.

Comment: Indeed, at the level of the C++ language as defined by the Standard, it's just "undefined behavior" and there's nothing more to say.  If you want an "under the hood" explanation for why this particular behavior happens on your particular system in this particular case, there is likely a reason, but it will depend on the details of your system, which you haven't said what it is.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++. So it's basically just undefined behavior that is coincidentally correct?

Comment: Even if you do initialize `n`, give it too high a value and `visited` and `mat` will blow the snot out of the stack. On a desktop PC that too-big value for `n` could be as low as a couple hundred. A user-controlled variable length array is just asking for mystery bugs when the user overflows the stack. Don't do it.

Comment: @BobWang You have the right of it, but I'd word it "Coincidentally what I expected."